# Apparently, the ":" on my if statement is invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am currently trying to create team selection code for my python video game.

Unfortunately, it keeps highliting the ":" of my if statement and saying that it is invalid syntax, even if i change the if statement for another. I tried everything, but after all, it IS an if statement, and i can't do much.

Heres my minimal recreation of the problem. The structure is important as there is netwroking code there;

```
team1=[]
team2=[]
if (len(team1)+len(team2)):
    if team1==team2:
        rand = (random.choice([team1, team2])
        if rand == "team1":
            team1.append(username)
        else:
            team2.append(username)
    else:
        if team1>=team2:
            team1.append(username)
        else:
            team2.append(username)
else:
    team1.append(username)
```

Comment: When you see a weird syntax error, always remember to check the previous line.

Comment: "Of my `if` statement" and code contains no less than four of them. Hint please?

Comment: Hint: Do you close all those brackets on `rand = (...)` properly? If your editor has a "rainbow brackets" option, might want to turn that on.

Comment: check the brackets. It does not match `rand = (random.choice([team1, team2])`

Comment: Also, username is not defined so your example doesn't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the stray '(' you have before `random.choice([team1, team2])`.  Delete it so it becomes:

```
rand = random.choice([team1, team2])
```

Comment: No need for name calling (even of yourself).  Notice the only two outcomes you have is team1.append(username) or team2.append(username) this means you can usually collapse your code to a single if/else statement.

Comment: The code is mostly just networking stuff that i had to remove to post it here, so i do have reasons.

Comment: Also, your first condition (len(team1)+len(team2)) checks if both lists are empty.  A better way to write that is `not team1 and not team2` as you don't have to sum two numbers only check if it's non-0.